# Верстка flexbox. Как выровнять текст внутри по левому краю

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Прошу прощения, если мой вопрос покажется глупым. Перепробовала различные свойства, но не могу добиться необходимого эффекта. Сейчас блоки и сам текст внутри по центру, мне же нужно, чтобы и сами блоки и текст внутри был по левому краю. Не могу понять какие свойства конкретно нужно изменить. Пробовала менять `justify-content`, `align-items`, `flex-direction`, но все остается на своих прежних местах совершенно не изменяясь.

И как добиться того, чтобы оба эти блока не выравнивались друг под друга и кнопка "Выбрать" не уезжала вниз, а оставалась сразу под текстом?
Привожу код.

**HTML**:

```
 <div class="pricing pricing--rabten">
            <div class="pricing__item">

                <h3 class="pricing__title">Тариф</h3>
                <p class="pricing__sentence">тариф</p>

                <ul class="pricing__feature-list">
                    <li class="pricing__feature">контент</li>
                    <li class="pricing__feature">контент</li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="pricing__item">

                <h3 class="pricing__title">Стоимость</h3>
                <ul class="pricing__feature-list">
                <li class="pricing__feature">Размещение на 6 месяцев</li>
                <li class="pricing__feature">Размещение на 1 год</li>
                <div class="pricing__price">
                    <span class="pricing__anim pricing__anim--1">
                            <span class="pricing__currency">&#8381;</span>12 000
                    </span>
                    <span class="pricing__anim pricing__anim--2">
                            <span class="pricing__period">за год</span>
                    </span> 
                    </ul>
                    <button class="pricing__action">Выбрать</button>
                </div>

            </div>

    </section>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pricing {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 3em;
}

.pricing__item {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 330px;
  flex: 0 1 330px;
}

.pricing__feature-list {
  text-align: left;
}

.pricing__action {
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.pricing__action:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас ошибки в html (`div` не может лежать в `ul`, должна быть `li`, с `section` не понятно что хотели) +  `align-items: flex-start;`

Чтобы кнопка "выбрать" шла сразу за списком, то у `ul.pricing__feature-list` нужно обнулить нижний отступ: `ul.pricing__feature-list {margin-bottom: 0px; }`,
а если еще и сдвинуть левее, то кнопке нужно будет добавить отступ слева, примерно, на 40px (столько же, сколько и у `ul` по-умолчанию ~40px).

Предполагаю, что так:

```css
.pricing {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 3em;
}

.pricing__item {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 330px;
  flex: 0 1 330px;
}

.pricing__feature-list {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.pricing__action {
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.pricing__action:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing pricing--rabten">
   <div class="pricing__item">

     <h3 class="pricing__title">Тариф</h3>
     <p class="pricing__sentence">тариф</p>

     <ul class="pricing__feature-list">
       <li class="pricing__feature">контент</li>
       <li class="pricing__feature">контент</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   
   <div class="pricing__item">
     <h3 class="pricing__title">Стоимость</h3>
     <ul class="pricing__feature-list">

       <li class="pricing__feature">Размещение на 6 месяцев</li>
       <li class="pricing__feature">Размещение на 1 год</li>

       <li class="pricing__price">
         <span class="pricing__anim pricing__anim--1">
           <span class="pricing__currency">&#8381;</span>
           12 000
         </span>
         <span class="pricing__anim pricing__anim--2">
           <span class="pricing__period">за год</span>
         </span>
       </li>
     </ul>

     <button class="pricing__action">Выбрать</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, все наконец-то встало на свои места ) Хотела еще только уточнить, каким образом сделать, чтобы кнопка "Выбрать" не выравнивалась по нижнему краю бокса?

Comment: подправила ответ.

Comment: Не реагирует на это кнопка, остается на своем месте

Comment: Но у меня в примере среагировала

Comment: Будем экспериментировать ) Спасибо большое за помощь!